# Federated Security/STS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wif, claims-based-identity, federated-identity

I have a asp.net site that uses federated security for authenticating the user.  Therefore a user navigates to the url which is redirected to a login page and if successful gets routed back to the main application.  What I need to do is somehow have the main application allow some code to be ran before being redirected to the login page.  This is because the intial request may have some query string parameters that I need to store in the users session as the request back to the main application is dropping them.

Is this possible... any thoughts or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this may help:

You can turn off the WIF’s built-in redirection of unauthenticated sessions by modifying web.config file:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
    <service>
        ......
        <federatedAuthentication>
            <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="false"
            ......
```

and once your reconstruct your query string, you can update audienceUri and realm.